# Java lwjgl&slick2d game gui and hud?

Tags: java, user-interface, interface, 2d, lwjgl

I'm pretty new to Java and currently working on a little game, just to test what I'm able to do with Java. But a random problem encountered: I have no clue how to make a GUI (Menu with Singleplayer, Multiplayer, Options,...) and a HUD (Graphical displaying of values [Life, Mana, Experience...]) How the title already says: I'm using the libraries jinput, lwjgl, lwjgl_util and Slick2D. My window is rendered via lwjgl's Display classes. Here's my code for the Main.class:

```
public class Main 
{
    public static int disWidth = 800;
    public static int disHeight =600;


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        initDisplay();
        initGL();
        initGame();


        gameLoop();
//        initGui();


        cleanUp();
    }

    private static void initGame()
    {
        Game.game = new Game();
    }

    private static void getInput()
    {
        Game.game.getInput();
    }

    private static void initGui()
    {
//Render the gui
    }

    private static void update()
    {
       Game.game.update();
//       GUI.gui.update() or something
    }

    private static void render()
    {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glLoadIdentity();


        Game.game.render();


        Display.update();
        Display.sync(60);
    }

    private static void initGL()
    {
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glOrtho(0, Display.getWidth(), 0, Display.getHeight(), -1, 1);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

        glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

        glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    private static void gameLoop()
    {        
        Time.init();

        int frames = 0;
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        long totalTime = 0;

        while(!Display.isCloseRequested())
        {
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            long passed = now - lastTime;
            lastTime = now;
            totalTime += passed;

            if(totalTime >= 1000000000)
            {
                System.out.println(frames);
                totalTime = 0;
                frames = 0;
            }

            Time.update();
            getInput();
            update();
            render();
            frames++;
        }



    }

    private static void cleanUp()
    {
        Display.destroy();
        Keyboard.destroy();
    }


    private static void initDisplay()
    {
        try 
        {
            Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(disWidth, disHeight));
            Display.create();
            Keyboard.create();
        }
        catch (LWJGLException ex) 
        {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try and check TWL. This I suppose is one of the way to implements a GUI in a LWJGL environment, although it's quite difficult the approach (due maybe to the xml part) and it's not so well documented (in my opinion)

You can also try to put the main Display class of LWJGL inside a standard Swing Canvas using the function to set its parent.

I need a GUI myself and I am learning TWL